# Regarding twilio queued phone number

Tags: twilio

I need help. I am trying to list all the available queued using REST API. Is there any way to grouped currently available queued phone number separately. Let say i have three group on my phone tree called Collection department (press 1), Sales department (press 2) and Inside sales department (press 3). Now if more than one user dial phone to each department pressing their respective number then phone are going on the queue in twilio. So i want to make a queued group according to those department. So how could i get this scenario on my application using twilio REST API. Is this possible ? if so then let me explain with some good example.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Twilo evangelist here.

You can make as many queues as you want, so in your case you can just create three different Queues (one named "Collections", one named "Sales" and one named "InsideSales"), and then based on the option that the caller just `[<Enqueue>][1]` the caller into the correct queue.

To start you need to create a phone menu.  The [Phone Menu HowTo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/phonemenu) shows you how to use the PHP helper libraries to create a basic menu using the `[<Say>][3]` and `[<Gather>][4]` verbs.  It also shows how to process the callers menu selection using Gathers [*action*](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action) parameter.

For your application, once the user selects a menu item you want to place them into a call Queue.  The [Call Queue HowTo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/callqueue) show you how to use the PHP helper libraries to send a caller to a Queue using the `<Enqueue>` verb.

In the Call Queue HowTo, notice that when using the PHP helper library you pass a string into the [Enqueue function](http://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/twiml.html?highlight=enqueue#enqueue).  This is the name of the queue I want to send the caller to.  If a Queue with that name does not yet exist, Twilio will automatically create it for you, otherwise that call is simple added to the existing queue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Devin, I am using PHP libraries of twilio REST API and OpenVBX for my development.How could i achieve that using either twilio REST API or openVBX.Please give me some code base example so i get myself more clear.

Comment: Edited my answer with some more details.  Hope that helps.